Serialport not accessible from Electron after appx compilation
I created a React application packaged with Electron that uses a USB barcode scanner which communicates through a serial port (USB Serial Device (COM4)), and I’m using the serialport/node-serialport package.
Once the application is compiled into an appx (using electron2appx based on electron-windows-store), I can no longer communicate with the barcode scanner through the serial port, even though it works perfectly well in development and in the build (@electron-forge).
After installing and launching the appx, I am able to list the COM ports on the PC, but when I scan a barcode, the scanner shows an error as if nothing is listening.
The issue seems to be related to how Windows Apps and/or Universal Windows Platform (UWP) function.
Here is my AppxManifest file :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
   xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
   xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
   xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10">
  <Identity Name="SUPERAPP"
    ProcessorArchitecture="x64"
    Publisher="My Compgny"
    Version="3.0.3.0" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>SUPERAPP</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Reserved</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Description>SUPERAPP</Description>
    <Logo>assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="en-us" />
  </Resources>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14316.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14316.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="inputInjectionBrokered" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="appDiagnostics" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="appCaptureSettings"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="videosLibrary"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="musicLibrary"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="sharedUserCertificates"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="userAccountInformation"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="removableStorage"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="appointments"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="contacts"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="phoneCall"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="blockedChatMessages"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="objects3D"/>
    <rescap:Capability Name="internetClient"/>
    <rescap:Capability Name="internetClientServer"/>
    <rescap:Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer"/>
    <rescap:Capability Name="allJoyn"/>
    <iot:Capability Name="lowLevelDevices"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="lowLevel"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
    <DeviceCapability Name="usb" >
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="classId:02 * *"/>
        <Function Type="name:cdcControl"/>
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
    <DeviceCapability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="humanInterfaceDevice" />
  </Capabilities>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="SUPERAPP" Executable="app\SUPERAPP.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
      <uap:VisualElements
        BackgroundColor="#C43B3B"
        DisplayName="SUPERAPP"
        Square150x150Logo="assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
        Description="SUPERAPP">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
</Package>

I’ve added just about every possible permission, but nothing changes.
I searched through the Windows Event Viewer, but I can't find anything.
Do you have any idea?
